# Are there any good 3rd party GUI products for Python?

Tags: python, user-interface

In .Net you have companies like DevEpxress, and Infragistics that offer a range of GUI widgets.  Is there any market like that for Python GUI widgets?  I'm thinking specifically about widgets like the DevExpress xtraGrid Suite.

Edit 01-16-09:  For Example:

http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/NET/OnlineDemos.xml
http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/

http://www.infragistics.com/products/default.aspx

Comment: nobody got what you are talking about. Maybe link to the sites so they can see what you mean

Comment: S.Lott:  'Good' point :) I am thinking of 3rd party GUI Widget sets as can be found at the sites I point to above?  I ask because most of the  UI sites I see for Python seem to indicate that I would need to roll my own.
Mike

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of GUI Toolkits available for Python. Obviously, the toolkit you choose will determine your selection of 3rd party widgets.

**The Contenders**

Python comes with [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) which is easy to use, but not great looking.

There are some very popular cross platform GUI toolkits borrowed from C/C++ that have a lot of external widgets: [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), [pyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt), [pyFLTK](http://pyfltk.sourceforge.net/), [pyGtk](http://www.pygtk.org/)

I also know of, but have not used some of the other toolkits that are out there: [PyGUI](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/), [Easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/),  [PythonCard](http://pythoncard.sourceforge.net/)

**My Choice**

I'm a fan of [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/). They have a nice selection of widgets, some great examples that come with the [install](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#binaries), good [documentation](http://www.wxpython.org/onlinedocs.php), a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394621), and an active community.

WxWidgets has additional components offered by the community called [wxCode](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/).

Quote about wxPython from the creator of Python:

> wxPython is the best and most mature cross-platform GUI toolkit, 
>   given a number of constraints. The only reason wxPython isn't the 
>   standard Python GUI toolkit is that Tkinter was there first.
>
> -- *Guido van Rossum*

Answer (score 1):

The popular Python GUI toolkits are usually wrappers around external (usually C, C++) libraries. So whatever 3rd party products those external libraries have, Python code can benefit (by minimal manual wrapping even in case the 3rd party solution does not provide Python wrappers by default).

Answer (score 1):

[wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) is a wrapper around [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/), LGPL (approximately) and very comprehensive
[pyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) is a similair wrapper around [QT](http://qtsoftware.com/products), it's available as GPL or commercial

Although QT is now under the LGPL pyQT is a separate commercial product, it may be that they now release it under the LGPL or a community effort might now produce a LGPL alternative.

Both run on MS/Linux/Mac and are pretty comprehensive, there are excellent communities and books for both.

Comment: Actually, wxWidgets licensing is more liberal that LGPL, it adds an exception for linking your binary without the restrictions the LGPL invoke - http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm

Comment: Qt version 4.5 (to be release around March 2009) will also be licensed under the LGPL v2.1 - http://www.qtsoftware.com/about/licensing/nokia-adds-lgpl-to-qt-licensing-model

Comment: Evan: Qt will be LGPL, but PyQt has its own license. It hasn't yet been determined if PyQt will be licensed LGPL for Qt 4.5

Answer (score 1):

All Python GUI tools has nowhere close or comparable to C#.Net GUI like DevExpress, Infragistic, Telerik, ComponentOne. The quality of those GUI will never be able match the capabilities offered by .Net GUI. C# programming has superior set of WSIWYG programming tools to build multiplatform app like Visual Studio(for windows/mac), Unity3D (for games), Blend(for web), Xamarin(mobile app). However on the downside it doesn't have as much as Python package or library for computation. So to bridge the gap usually I'll build interface completely on C#.Net and if it requires extensive calculation i'll call Python script by using IronPython for .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Heaps of GUI apis are available. PyQT, PtGTK, Tkinter...

-T

Answer (score 0):

There's also [wxPython](http://wxpython.org/), which is a wrapper around [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) which is quite popular, works on many platforms and liberally licensed.

QT would probably be the other one I would look at, especially now that the next release will be licensed under the LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any commercial packages for GUI in Python but as I know Kivy is a good option for creating fast and beautiful GUI
 https://github.com/kivy/kivy